# COM+ Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, com+

Is it possible to use visual studio to create an install package for COM+? If so how can I do it? I have successfully installed COM and had it registered but I have been unsuccessful with COM+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and after a complicated process I was able to do this using custom action and by using some of the apis provided by microsoft.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309561(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can easily build MSI’s that deploy COM+ packages using the WiX toolset which integrates with Visual Studio.

WiX Homepage: http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Com+ documentation: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/complus_xsd_index.htm

For a sample see: http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson6.php#6.11